# Portrait(View Controller A) to forcefully Landscape (View Controller B) coming with half black cutoff screen

Tags: ios, orientation, landscape, portrait

Portrait(View Controller A) to forcefully Landscape (View Controller B).
Some times View Controller B is not rotating fully in Landscape, Coming with half black cut off.
Please check below links.

[In this, it is coming correctly in landscape mode to ViewController B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PQxE.jpg)

[In this, It tries to change to landscape but not happened fully and stuck in middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHieh.jpg)